# Can we specify the number of output tokens generated by sha in java?

Tags: java, token, sha

I want to check file duplication using token generation. For tokens I am using SHA but the tokens returned have a long length. so can I specify the number of tokens to be returned by sha in java?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/does-the-sha-hash-function-always-generate-a-fixed-length-hash#answer-2148

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  SHA generates a checksum, not tokens.   The size (in bits) of the checksum is determined by which version of SHA that you use.